# How to make a table column take up the same space as multiple other columns

Tags: css, html-table

I'm looking to create something like this: [image]

But can't figure out what's the best way to make the 15 year and 30 year headers take as much space as the 4 columns below them.

Is there anything simple I could add to the first pair of `<th>` below? e.g: colsize, colwidth etc

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     ... more code here
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can use colspan=4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **colspan** attribute to **th** tag like so:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">1</th>
      <th colspan="4">2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Number 4 defines the number of columns a cell should span.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. I knew there was an attribute but couldn't remember it. Thank you!

Comment: @jgozal I'm glad I could help :)